# Bound for the derivative of a holomorphic map in the disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the unitary disk, and let $f: D \to D$ be a holomorphic map. Prove that
$$
  \left|f^\prime(z)\right| \leq \frac{1 - |f(z)|^2}{1 - |z|^2} \qquad \forall z\in D.
$$

Comment: Do you recognize this as the Schwarz-Pick Theorem?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Apply Schwartz-Pick for a suitable composition of your function and an automorphism of the unit disc. If $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D} $  and $a$ inside the disc , then $\left|\frac{f(z)-a}{1-\bar{a}f(z)}\right|\le \left|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}\right|$ . This will give you the result.